# Replace randomly RDD values to null with scala spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, null, rdd

I have a csv file containing almost 15000 records. Each line contain 3 types of data devided by a tab (\t). I Actually want to replace randomly the second column value into null ! Maybe I will keep 8000 as they are and replace 7000 values to null.

Any help please with scala (spark)?

This is how it looks like: [image]

Answer (score 1):

1. read data as dataframe
2. generate a new column say `rnd` which is a random number from 0 to 1
3. make col2 = col2 when `rnd` < 0.5 (if you want to make 50% values null) else null

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, rand, when}
import spark.implicits._

spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", "\t").csv(<your_path>)
.withColumn("rnd", rand())
.withColumn("col2", when($"rnd" < 0.5, $"col2").otherwise(lit(null).cast(<col2_datatype_here>)))
```

Comment: look to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

@amelie, notice `$` in front of "rnd" in when condition in my answer.

You were supposed to do a column comparison, not value comparison.

`PS`: Not able to put comment as I am a stackoverflow newbie, hence a separate answer.

Comment: and this is not working too. 
when adding $ here's the error:
Error:(22, 37) value $ is not a member of StringContext
      .withColumn("ECnumber", when(($"rnd" < 0.5)  , "ECnumber")

Comment: You need to `import spark.implicits._`

Comment: Use col("rnd") instead of $"rnd" then, `col` should ne imported from functions first.

Comment: can you please show me how can see/save the result ?

Comment: the result is totally false. Thank you for your help